# Anyway to fix this SSL Handshake error on OkHttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

This is the exception the user is getting. I can load the exact same URL just fine on my phone.

```
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:444)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at sy.a(MyCode.java:360)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at sy.service(MyCode.java:174)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at aoc.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      : Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x6f64d25a00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      : error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:641 0x6f5e670aa0:0x00000001)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      : error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:800 0x6fc1a7c2d7:0x00000000)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
11-14 14:22:10.007 16863 16948 W sy      :  ... 43 more
```

Is it possible to somehow allow this to work?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've removed the code for the `TrustManager` as it was pointed out to me that it violates Play Store policy. So now I'm just wondering why I get this error and if the user can do anything to fix it? Strangely enough, he is able to load that same resource on Chrome and even on my own app using the Android System WebView. Just can't load it on this one piece of code that uses OkHttp. And I'm able to load it everywhere, even on that piece of code.

Code that was removed:

<strike>This is how I create my OkHttp client:</strike>

    <strike>final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }</strike>

```
                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
```

Comment: You will not be able to ship this app on the Play Store, due to that `trustAllCerts` implementation, assuming that this code is in the app (and not in a test suite or something).

Comment: It is, and the app is published. I didn't know that wasn't allowed. The only reason I have that is because this is for something totally harmless, zero danger, and even if someone got faked it, all they could do is send harmless information. But thanks for the warning, I'll go ahead and remove it.

Comment: "I didn't know that wasn't allowed" -- they have been banning apps that blindly accept all SSL certificates via custom `TrustManager` implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I've already edited my code to remove it. I've never gotten a warning, their documentation says it warns you if you have it. I think maybe their test doesn't catch mine because it is on a very specific place that their tests would never be able to execute due to some external hardware requirements. Not a big deal, this isn't a very common issue.